# mysql doesn't work with Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Hi I am new to **Ruby on Rails**. I created a new project using **Aptana Studio** and started the server using `rails server` command. But when I'm trying to access the server via browser I'm getting the following error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7P0FE.png

```
Access denied for user root@localhost (using password: NO)


      socket = socket.to_s unless socket.nil?

      connect user, pass, host, port, database, socket, flags
    end

def self.default_query_options
```

Rails.root: /home/tapas/RubyWorkspace/myproj

```
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
mysql2 (0.3.18) lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `connect'
mysql2 (0.3.18) lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `new'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `mysql2_connection'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/home/tapas/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/home/tapas/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:567:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:384:in `connection'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:371:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
```

I tried using all host:port combinations e.g. 3000,3306..etc ,but nothing works. And here's how my `database.yml` file looks like.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9ok1.png

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: mysql_dev
  pool:5
  username: root
  password: tapaskumar
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  host: localhost
  port: 3306

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: mysql_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: tapaskumar
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  host: localhost
  port: 3306

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: mysql2_prod
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: tapaskumar
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
```

When I'm trying to access mysql from terminal, it works fine. Also I installed mysql using this command.

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev`

And also have the mysql gem installed for the project. I'm unable to figure out whats wrong.

Comment: Well, for starters it seems like your app is attempting to connect to the MySQL database without a password. Unfortunately I can't tell you why, but start by double checking your settings.

Comment: The title of the question could be more descriptive.

Comment: what's the command you use to login to your sql server from the command line? do you specify the user as "root" there as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was editing some global database.yml file previously .Then i found out a specific database.yml file on config folder of the project directory ,which i think is specific to that project.After few indentation errors ,Finally got it.